# Titanium: Show index filter in TableView (like in the contacts app)

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator

Has anyone been able to do this? Coming from Objective-C, I know that you just need to implement a delegate method in the UITableView, but has this been ported in Titanium? I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Go figure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
tableView.index= [ {title: 'A', index: 0}, {title: 'B', index: 1} ]
```